# When using Mac my bluetooth commands send to the device repeat endlessly

Tags: javascript, macos, bluetooth, blazor

So i finally got my bluetooth commands working to send data from my browser to my bluetooth cutting device.

Im making a C# blazor app with javascript to handle the bluetooth connection. Using bluetooth web api.

It has a test command that it can send at the push of a button, and a reset position command.

When i use windows this all works fine. I send the shape to cut and the machine cuts it. Im using google chrome because it is the only one that works with the bluetooth api. However when i switch to the mac. The shape is repeatedly cut out and it has no end.

I also don't get the log `console.log("Write operation successful");` to let me know the await command has finished. Which i do get on windows.

Not sure how to define the issue better than this. Basically mac is being its normal ridiculous self.

I want to only send the command once.

Here is the javascript writeValue that sends data to the bluetooth

```
export async function writeValue(deviceId, serviceId, characteristicId, value) {
    var device = getDevice(deviceId);

    console.log("START WRITE VALUE.JS", value);

    if (device.gatt.connected) {

        var service = await device.gatt.getPrimaryService("e2088282-4fde-42f9-bb22-6ec3c7ed8f91");

        var characteristic = "6d92661d-f429-4d67-929b-28e7a9780912";

        var ch = await service.getCharacteristic(characteristic);

        try {
            await ch.writeValue(new Uint8Array(value));

            // await ch.writeValue(new Uint8ClampedArray(value));
            console.log("Write operation successful");

        } catch (error) { console.error("Error during write operation:", error); }
    }
    else {
        await sleep(1000);
        await writeValue(deviceId, serviceId, characteristicId, value);
    }
}
```

I don't think i need to share more code. This is going to be a device issue couple with maybe a missing javascript command or maybe a 'End process' command i need to add to something somewhere.

Any clues tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
Hard to find this detail but Mac only let you send 152 bytes at a time to bluetooth devices unlike windows with which allows higher